# Howto install Arduino IDE 2.2 from the ZIP version on Ubuntu 23? (without install.sh)

Tags: command-line, software-installation, .desktop, arduino

This question has been asked before on the [Arduino.cc forum](https://forum.arduino.cc) and is about the missing `install.sh` file in the .ZIP file of the current version (As of Novermber 2023 it is 2.2.1).

This "inconvenience" has been reported [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/linux-installation-of-2-0-rc3/952913)...

> Please point me to installation instructions for the new RC3. The download (64bit Linux) does not contain an install.sh file to do the install with. I have searched for instructions but they all seem to apply to older versions that DO contain the file. [...]

...but was not solved by the [canonical answer](https://docs.arduino.cc/software/ide-v2/tutorials/getting-started/ide-v2-downloading-and-installing#linux) which only applies to the *AppImage version*.

How could an `install.sh` for the zipped 2.2.x version look like?

Comment: Do you want to install it or do you want to use it from a folder?

Comment: @SohanArafat: This question/answer is about the ZIP file version. It is _not_ about the AppImage version. My answer only makes the extracted contents of the ZIP file more comfortable to use by integrating them into the Ubuntu desktop system.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to register the Arduino IDE 2.2.1 with the (K)Ubuntu Desktop is the following. It is not expressed as a complete script, but rather as distinct steps:

1. Download the ZIP file of [current version](https://www.arduino.cc/en/software#future-version-of-the-arduino-ide) of the Arduino IDE 2.2.1 to `~/Downloads` (Of course, change the name in the following to the actual version)
2. Execute the following

   ```
   cd /opt
   sudo unzip ~/Downloads/arduino-ide_2.2.1_Linux_64bit.zip
   sudo ln -s arduino-ide_2.2.1_Linux_64bit/arduino-ide arduino-ide
   ```

   The last line makes it easier to change the installed version without changing the rest. Now you could just link to new versions by changing only the link.
3. Create directories for shortcuts and icons in your home directory. This is not mandatory, but can be applied to unify the approach for other programs as well.

   ```
   mkdir ~/.Desktop.Shortcuts
   mkdir ~/.Desktop.Icons
   ```
4. Download and add [this PNG Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbDAj.png) to `~/.Desktop.Icons`.
5. Add the following text as file `Arduino-IDE.desktop` in `~/.Desktop.Shortcuts`:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Exec=/opt/arduino-ide
   Icon=~/.Desktop.Icons/Arduino-IDE-Icon.png
   Name[en_US]=Arduino IDE
   Name=Arduino IDE
   Path=
   StartupNotify=false
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   ```
6. Create two symbolic links to the `Arduino-IDE.desktop` file:

   1. Create a desktop symbol:

      ```
      sudo ln -s $HOME/.Desktop.Shortcuts/Arduino-IDE.desktop $HOME/Desktop/Arduino-IDE.desktop
      ```
   2. Register as system app:

      ```
      sudo ln -s $HOME/.Desktop.Shortcuts/Arduino-IDE.desktop /usr/share/applications/Arduino-IDE.desktop
      ```
7. Finally add your user to the `dialup` group to grant access to the serial ports (also USB-to-serial).

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G dialout $(whoami)
   ```

Now you should have integrated the contents of the ZIP file in your Ubuntu system like the `install.sh` script did.